# Does resb create a pointer or an uninitialized variable?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Does 'var resb 1' declare a pointer or an uninitialized variable of 1 byte? What would be its c equivalent?

Comment: Note that the BSS is guaranteed to be zero-initialized on all modern OSes.  Some people call this "uninitialized", but I think that's confusing terminology.

Comment: Thanks...small Things like this adds confusion and are hard to find answer on.

Answer (score 3):

The `resb` directive reserves the indicated number of bytes of storage in the BSS section, in your case 1 byte.  By writing `var` before `resb`, you set the symbol `var` to be located at the beginning of that storage.  This is pretty much equal to writing

```
static char var;
```

in C.

Comment: then why do I need to write [var] to access the content?

Comment: @BijayShrestha Because in nasm syntax, all memory references use square brackets.  There is no `offset` keyword; `var` is always the value of the symbol (i.e. the address of the buffer) and `[var]` is always the value at that address.

Comment: But doesnt that mean var is pointer to value at [val] since it stores address. So is it correct if I say [var] is same as *var?

Comment: @Zeroishero To add 2 in assembler use `add byte [var],1`, in C use `var += 2;`.

Comment: @Zeroishero: In C, symbols are associated with a type, and the default thing to do with a symbol is access the memory at that location.  You need `&var` in C to get the address.  In NASM it's the opposite, and symbols are *not* associated with any implied size, they're just zero-width references to the space between two bytes, i.e. the end of one byte and the start of another.  The *value of* the symbol itself is its address, like `mov edi, var` to put the address in a register.  (vs. if you did `xyz equ 2`, then `mov edi, xyz` would be `mov edi, 2`).  The value *at* the symbol is `[var]`.

Comment: MASM is the opposite: `mov al, var` is a load, and you need `mov edi, OFFSET var` to use the address as an immediate.  I like NASM because you don't have to look up the definition of a symbol to see whether it's an EQU constant or a label to see whether `mov edi, symbol` is a `mov r32, imm32` or a `mov r32, r/m32`.

Comment: In the context of OP question and comment I would write that `var resb 1` in C example as `static char varContent;` `#define var ((void*)(&varContent))`, and then you are right the `*var` (`var[0]` is maybe even closer to asm syntax, especially if you will start to use displacements and index registers) in C is similar like `[var]` in assembly. And then those dereferences in C must also cast the pointer type, which is what you have to do in assembly, always write instruction accessing memory in a way that the assembler knows data-width to be processed, i.e. `mov [var],al` vs `mov byte [val],0`

Comment: @Ped7g What I mean is that if you write `static char varContent` in C, then the C compiler exactly emits `varContent resb 1` (modulo symbol decoration).